# How to build a new date column based on the previous and last value changed?

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I am looking to build a query in SQL where I am adding a new date column which will return the date when the price has been changed.

My current dataset looks like this now:

```
Product_id  Current_date    Price
2001         11/1/19         57
2001         11/2/19         57
2001         11/3/19         58
2001         11/20/19        58
2001         11/21/19        60
2001         11/22/19        60
2001         11/29/19        60
2001         11/30/19        72
2001         11/29/19        72
2001         11/30/19        72
```

And I would like to add a new column 'changed date' which will be calculated based on - if price did not change return previous date, if price has changed return current date)

looking like this:

```
product_id  current_date    Price   **Changed_Date** (if price did not change return previous 
                                                      date, 
                                                      if price changed return current date)
2001           11/1/19     57     11/1/19
2001           11/2/19     57     11/1/19
2001           11/3/19     58     11/3/19
2001           11/20/1     60     11/20/19
2001           11/21/19    60     11/20/19
2001           11/22/19    60     11/20/19
2001           11/29/19    60     11/20/19
2001           11/28/19    72     11/28/19
2001           11/29/19    72     11/28/19
2001           11/30/19    72     11/28/19
```

Could anyone help with ideas on best functions to use in SQL to get this outcome? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Specify MySQL version - it is critical for your task.

Answer (score 0):

In your example data, the prices are only increasing.  If that is the case, the simplest method is a cumulative min:

```
select t.*,
       min(current_date) over (partition by product_id, price) as changed_date
from t;
```

If this is not the case -- particularly if prices can return to previous prices -- then you have a gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest solution in this case is probably the difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       min(date) over (partition by product_id, price, (seqnum - seqnum_2)) as change_date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by current_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id, price order by current_date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference in row numbers identifies adjacent rows with the same price.

Comment: It's good to mention that `OVER PARTITION` would work only with MySQL 8.

Comment: @user12460577 . . . This code assumes that there are no complete duplicates.  If rows are completely duplicated, I would recommend that you remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, guys! 
@Gordon,  I tried the example you recommended and is working partially, and why I am saying partially is that for some rows doesn't return the expected results, this may be to do with how the over partition is done?

see example below:

```
product_id   current_date        price             changed date
2001         10/4/19              60                10/4/19
2001         10/6/19              60                10/4/19
2001         10/7/19              60                10/4/19
2001         10/12/19             60                10/4/19
2001         10/13/19             57                10/13/19
2001         10/18/19             57                10/13/19
2001         10/20/19             57                10/13/19
 -----did not work for the below dates (should have been 10/13/19 as changed date, because price did not change)                                                                  
2001        10/24/19              57                10/24/19                                         
2001        10/24/19              57                10/24/19
2001        10/25/19              57                10/24/19
```

Any suggestions on how I could change this?
Thank you again